# display option to delete files if user type is correct

Tags: php

I have a simple file-sharing page that allows the user to upload images and display the directory contents in a list. I have 2 users in my Database, an I want to make it so only one can delete files. My database has a type column for the users and these values are 1 or 2. Here is my code:

```
    <body>
<?php include "view/header.php" ?>
<div id="main">
    <h2>Image to be uploaded</h2>
    <form id="upload_form" action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload">
        <input type="file" name="file1"><br />
        <input id="upload_button" type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <h2>Images in the directory</h2>
    <?php if (count($files) == 0) : ?>
        <p>No images have been uploaded.</p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach($files as $filename) :
            $file_url= $image_dir . '/' . $filename;
            $delete_url= '.?action=delete&filename=' . urlencode($filename);
        ?>
            <li>
                <a href= "<?php echo $delete_url;?>">
                    <img src= "images/delete.png" alt= "Delete"></a>
                <a href= "<?php echo $file_url;?>">
                    <?php echo $filename;?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
 <div id="footerholder">
    <div id="footer">
    <?php include "view/footer.php" ?>
</div>
```

This is what my login page refers to:

```
<?php

$dsn= 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=file_share';
$username= 'root';
$password= '';

try {
    $db= new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); }

    catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error_message= $e->getMessage();
    echo "<p>An error occured while connecting to the database: $error_message </p>"; }

//Only run code below if form has been posted
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

if( isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])
   && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) ) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];  

    $sql= 'SELECT *
           FROM `users`
           WHERE `username` = :username
           AND `password` = :password
           LIMIT 1';  //SQL query with named placeholders

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  //Returns a PDOStatement class object
    $stmt->bindParam(':username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR,16);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password',$password,PDO::PARAM_STR,16);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $error = $stmt->errorInfo();//Debug 
    if($error[0] != '00000')
    printf('SQL Error: <pre>%s</pre>', print_r($error, true));

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn']= "true";
        header("Location: uploader.php");
    }
    else {
         echo 'Sorry username/password wrong';
         echo '<br><a href="login.php">Try Again</a></br>';
    }
```

Comment: you should never have a delete on a get request which that is a link.

Comment: Can you show how you select the user record?

Comment: Daniel's right. You *could* use a get as long as you check the user type before deleting, but it's best practice to post as well as checking.

Comment: I posted my code for the login check if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you have your user record in `$profile`:

```
<?php if($profile["type"] == 1){ ?>
    <li>
        <a href= "<?php echo $delete_url;?>">
            <img src= "images/delete.png" alt= "Delete">
        </a>
        <a href= "<?php echo $file_url;?>">
            <?php echo $filename;?>
        </a>
    </li> 
<?php } ?>
```

You should put the part that displays the delete link in a statement which checks the user type.

BTW, in your current code, if a hacker finds out that your delete url is .../?action=delete&filename=FILE_NAME, he could simple call that url with a file_name. So, you have to do 2 things:

1. Always check the user permissions on the server side too to make sure that nobody has changed your html to access that page or things like that.
2. Use MD5 on your link and add it to the end of the link. This MD5 could be MD5(link + your_name + "hello"), something impossible to guess. Your link would be like:

   `href=".../action=delete&filename=FILE_NAME&hash=d131dd02c5e6eec4"`

   And on your server side, check the md5 of the link with the passed hash. By doing this, no one can manipulate your link.

PS. What I suggested is just one way of doing the security of your website.

Comment: And also you must check your request to ensure that the current user really has a right to delete and haven't fabricated request to `delete.php` (even though he doesn't see the link on the page currently.)

Comment: Ok. Not sure about the $profile. How would I just check against my database and display the delete link if need be. Sorry, student here so please be patient with me. Also, the security isn't a huge factor as this is just a class project. Lastly, thank you for the help...much appreciated.